# Where do I install an outside mount for blinds?

Tags: windows, blinds

I'm installing faux wood blinds in my home.  I prefer the outside mount because it looks better on my windows, however the molding is a weird design.  The head casing and side casing don't meet at a nice 90 degree angle.  Instead, there is joining piece that connects the two casings at a 45 degree angle.  The joining piece is small, maybe an inch.  But if I'm hanging blinds, where should have them start: at the top of the head casing or the top of the side casing?

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your terminology. Are you installing them on top of the trim? When installing blinds on the outside they should ideally cover the trim around the window when closed. It should do that either because you raised it up high enough to do so or because the blinds themselves have a trim kit that does it.

Comment: Isn't the valence going to cover it either way? Two pictures of you holding it where you mean would help.

Comment: FYI, your 'answer' should be a comment under your own question. I'm still having a hard time visualizing this. Sounds like you need some small wedges as stand-offs to make the angle right.

Comment: Hi! You appear to have a couple of user accounts; please consider registering and merging them, which will allow you to comment on, edit and accept answers to your posts; if you want to do this, click "contact us" at the bottom of the page, then "I need to merge user profiles" and follow the instructions. Thanks!